# Regular expressions with checking that last group exists

Tags: regex, preg-match, string-matching

I have this kind of url structure of the site:

```
/some_url/{slug}/
```

Where {slug} have information about field ordering (only price and name), order direction (asc, desc), limit rows (30, 40 or empty) and presentation type (list or empty). For example:

```
/some_url/price_desc_30_list/
```

As you can see each group separated by underscore, but it true only for middle groups. Each group is optional, in previous example url consists of three groups `price_desc`, `30`, `list`. What i want is get each group value.

Currently my regexp is `(?:(price|name)_(asc|desc))?(?:_?(30|40))?(?:_?(list))?` but there is problem with underscores (i need them in the beggining of group only if previous group exists) so this url `/some_url/_30/` and this `/some_url/30/` both will be matched, but i need only `/some_url/30/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I tried something with this:

```
\/([^_\/]+)(?:_([^_\/]+)?_?)?(?:_([^_\/]+)?_?)?(?:_([^_\/]+)?_?)?\/$
```

And tested on [regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/lG8vC0).

Not sure why

```
\/([^_\/]+)(?:_([^_\/]+)?_?){0,3}\/$
```

wasn't working though :(

**EDIT: New regex**

`^\/(.*?)\/(?:(?<!\/_)(price|name)(?!_\/))?_?(?:(?<!\/_)(asc|desc)(?!_\/))?_?(?:(?<!\/_)(30|40)(?!_\/))?_?(?:(?<!\/_)(list)(?!_\/))?\/$`

[Tested](http://www.regex101.com/r/yF7hR0)

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead and prevents the match of a character followed by the set of characters inside the lookahead. E.g. `(list)(?!_\/)` prevents the match of `list_/` since `list` is followed by `_/`.

`(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind and prevents the match of a character preceded by the set of characters inside the lookbehind. E.g. `(?<!\/_)(list)` prevents the match of `/_list` since `list` is preceded by `/_`.

Comment: /some_url/price_desc_/ is matched

Comment: And there is one big minus, your regexp can take any string value, for example: /some_url/price_hahahahahaha/

Comment: @kirugan I made up another one. One thing though: I had to use the anchors because all the parameters after `/some_url/` were optional, so that the regex would validate any string (and capture partial matches). Also... there's a _lot_ of lookaheads/lookbehinds there to make sure of the training underscores.

Comment: Hmm ... it seems that this thing is working. What is all this `?!` signs mean ?

Comment: @kirugan Lol this 'thing' `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. It ensures that the character is not followed by certain characters inserted within the negative lookahead. If I have `mousse` and use a regex `s(?!s)`, the regex will find an `s` **not** followed by another `s`.

Comment: @kirugan I have put the explanation of the lookbehind and lookahead in my answer :)